# Polygon in MapView instead of CLCircularRegion

Tags: ios, swift3, cllocationmanager

How can I use polygon or any other shape instead of CLCircularRegion, 
I have studied that GoogleMaps support this feature, but apple mapview does not support?

Thanks

Comment: go through https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial